# Perl/Moose do not create the object but don't die if an attribute is wrong

Tags: perl, moose

Have the next package

```
package MyTest;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use Types::Path::Tiny qw(AbsPath AbsFile);

has 'file' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => AbsPath,
    required => 1,
    coerce => 1,
);
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

works (nearly) ok, so when use it

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Mytest;
use DDP;

my $t1 = MyTest->new(file => './t');    # the ./t is existing file in the filesystem
say $t1 ? "ok" : "no";

my $t2 = MyTest->new(file => './nonexistent_file');
say $t2 ? "ok" : "no";
p $t2;
```

says "ok" for both. and the `$t2->file` is `isa "Path::Tiny`

But, I don't want create the object if the file isn't really exists in the filesystem. So, the second (`$t2`) invocation should return `undef`.

Changing the

```
        isa => AbsPath,
```

to

```
        isa => AbsFile,
```

will check the existence of the file, but if it isn't exists - the script will die with the

```
Attribute (file) does not pass the type constraint because:  File '/tmp/nonexistent_file' does not exist
```

I don't want die, only want not create the `MyTest` instance and return undef if the file isn't exists or it isn't a plain file. If the file exists the file should be a `Path::Tiny` instance. (coerced from Str).

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to catch and discard expected errors:

```
use Try::Tiny;

my $instance = try {
    MyTest->new(file => './nonexistent_file');
} catch {
    # only mute the constraint errors
    return undef if /\AAttribute [(]\w+[)] does not pass the type constraint/;
    die $_;   # rethrow other errors
};
```

Mucking around with the constructor so that it returns `undef` on failure is not a good idea, as there is an implied contract that `->new` will always return a valid instance. In older Perl code, returning a special value on failure is considered OK, but this forces additional checks on the caller – and checks can be forgotten. Moose has taken a more robust route by using exeptions instead (thus *forcing* that they be handled), although in this specific case this does add a bit boilerplate.

If you want to hide this boilerplate, consider writing a factory method.

Comment: @jm666 In this specific case, that's indeed a much better solution (the case that the file doesn't exist is not exceptional, so this case should be handled by normal control flow). Consider posting it as an answer of your own :) In my answer I just tried to explain that errors are a good thing, and that they are easy to handle.

Answer (score 2):

I commented @amon's post, but changed my mind, because his solution is universal, and mine is handling only this special case, anyway posting it:

```
my $file = './nonexistent_file';
my $t2 = (-f $file) ? MyTest->new(file => $file) : undef;
```